# How to handle non- linear predictors in Decision Trees

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, cart, boosting

I have a data set of just 1800 rows. I am not sure about how to provide inputs for certain variables. For eg., I have a column called number of previous jobs, and the values lie between 1 and 10, with values greater than 5 together having a frequency of each of the values 1 , 2, 3 and 4. Also, the dependent variable has a staggered relationship with these values. 
These are the questions I have:

1. Do i send this column as continuous data? If yes, do I cap the
   values?
2. Or do i create categories like 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5+ as the
   relationship is staggered and this balances out the frequency of
   levels?

This is the first time I am working on Machine learning algorithms and would appreciate your guidance. If you need any clarifications, please do put it in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, your decision tree should be able to handle nonlinear effects, by splitting appropriately. My first instinct would be to simply include your data numerically, without capping.

Without knowing what kind of data you have, how many variables and so forth, we won't be able to tell you the "best" model here. Try different transformations of your variables and see how well they perform. Experiment a bit!

For this, split your data into a training and a test set. (Or, if you want to avoid overfitting on your test set, use a third partition as a validation set.) Or do actual cross-validation.

Finally, once you are comfortable with decision trees, take a look at [Random Forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest), which are a fast and very accurate generalization of decision trees.